# Why does PHP nested foreach loop displays only first row from sql database

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am trying to display a table from database using two nested foreach loops with some criteria. here is the code-

```
echo "<div class='container'>";
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed' style='width:95%' align='center'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Edit";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Delete";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Sl. No.";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Group";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Component";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Quantity";
echo "</th>";
echo "</tr>";
if($rslt->rowCount() > 0)
    {   
        foreach($rslt as $item)
        {
            foreach($rslt3 as $item3)
            {
               /*echo $item3['component'];
                if($item3['component']===$item['component'])
                {
                if($Qty>=$item3['Qty'])
                    {
                    $item3[Qty]=$item3[Qty]-$item[Qty];
                    */ 
                   //will implement this after the second loop starts working
                    $id = $item['entry_id'];
                    $Qty = $item['Qty'];
                    $group_ID = $item['group_ID'];
                    $component = $item['component'];
                    $vendor_ID = $item['vendor_ID'];
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<a href='production_edit.php?id=$id&Qty=$Qty&group_ID=$group_ID&component=$component&vendor_ID=$vendor_ID'>Edit</a>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<a href='production_delete.php?id=$id&vendor_ID=$vendor_ID'>Delete</a>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $item['entry_id'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $item['group_ID'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $item['component'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $item['Qty'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }

echo "</table></div><br>";
}
```

Now the problem here is when I use the second foreach loop the table displays the first entry in each table row... I am curious where I am at fault with this second foreach loop.. Thanks in advance

Comment: say print_r($rslt );

Comment: where is the $item, $item3 defined? plz post those assignment lines as well

Comment: @VigneswaranS actually i was using single foreach loop.. and all distinct entries were being displayed through it.. but now i need to compare these elements from another table entries.. therefore i have to add a second foreach for second table iteration... so here print_r() wouldnt help me. Thanks anyway..

Comment: what $rslt3 contains ? can you post print_r($rslt) and print_r($rslt3). what doing with $item3 . how you are comparing ?

Comment: $item, $item3 are defined in foreach() using $rslt, $rslt3 retrieved from db... they both are working perfectly...

Comment: @VigneswaranS
print_r($rslt) O/P = PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM sample.temp WHERE group_ID=1 ) 
print_r($rslt3) O/P = PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT component, Qty FROM sample.stock WHERE stock_ID=1 )

Comment: print_r($rslt) should give an array. any how you used   $vendor_ID = $item['vendor_ID']; in second loop. so you will get first entry only .  $item3['vendor_ID']; you should use.

Comment: @VigneswaranS  I am using $q = "SELECT * FROM sample.temp WHERE group_ID=$group_ID";
 $rslt = $dbo->query($q);
So this is not giving me an array... should i use array instead of all this?